# Data Science Communities for complete beginners

Tags: data, software-recommendation

Any recommendation as to where i can join communities and forums so i can get to learn Data Science please?

i am a total beginner and i'm having a hard time learning it alone.

Comment: Here? [Cross Validated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) Do you mean that you're looking for a tutor or an instructor?